# Union of two lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists say:

`a = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]`

`b = [2, 5, 6]`

After doing a union, I should get something like this (don't mind the order):

`c = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6]`

The final list should contain common elements only once and rest of elements (from both lists) should be copied as they are. Sets can't be used for this as they remove multiple occurrence of an element from the list, which isn't a union. What is a Pythonic way to do so?

Comment: What about 3 in your example?

Comment: `a = [1, 2, 2, 3]; b = [2, 5, 6]; a_set = set(a); c = a + [x for x in b if x not in a_set]`  / `c` => `[1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6]`

Comment: If this was a proper multiset union, you'd have *three* times `2` in your output, and include the `3`. I'm really not sure what you are trying to do here; perhaps you need to rethink your question. Otherwise, use `itertools.Counter()` objects: `c = list((Counter(a) + Counter(b)).elements())` (or just stick to `Counter()` objects all the way).

Comment: I've elaborated the question. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Perform a union, keeping repetition:

```
>>> c = a + b
[1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 6]
```

Perform a union, keeping repetition & order:

```
>>> c = sorted(a + b)
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Perform an union, no repetition in each list, but repetition allowed in final union, and keeped order:

```
>>> c = sorted(list(set(a)) + list(set(b)))
[1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

---

After clarification of the question, the goal is to build a list that take elements (including repetition) of, and then add elements of b if they are not in the new list.

```
>>> c = a + [e for e in b if e not in a]
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

---

After another clarification of the question, the goal is to build a list containing all elements of input list. But, if elements are in common, they are pushed the same number there

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def merge(a,b):
...   na, nb = Counter(a), Counter(b)
...   return list(Counter({k: max((na[k], nb[k])) for k in set(a + b)}).elements())
>>> merge([1, 2, 2, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6])
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6]
>>> merge([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 4])
[1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Wouldn't this give three 2's ?

Comment: I think you have one too many c =

Comment: Thanks, it's fixed. I initially assumed that the OP's example have errors (the `3` disapears), but i've added the command for get exactly what is asked.

Comment: Can you edit the answer please. I didn't intend to skip 3 in list c, so last part isn't required. I've updated the question. Thanks :)

Comment: Wait a minute. This isn't a union. Suppose a=[1,2,2,2,3] and b=[2,5,6]. Third part would result in c=[1,2,2,3,5,6] which should be c=[1,2,2,2,3,5,6].

Comment: So use the second line. Your example in OP seems to avoid repetition inside a and b. (only two `2` in c)

Comment: Yes it does because 2 was common in both a and b, so it was only inserted once. The second part in the answer simply adds two lists without considering common elements. I do want to avoid repetition but only for elements common in both lists, not the ones that are already repeated in original list. They should be inserted as they are. Please check updated question, and sorry for not making it clear the first time. Would appreciate another answer. :)

Comment: I not sure i'm understand, but i've edited the answer. (i can't create another because of the `put on hold` flag… you should consider be absolutely clear next times you ask a question, by providing more examples, without errors)

Comment: Last part won't work, if a=[1,2,3] and b=[2,2,4]. Answer would be [1,2,4] though it should be [1,2,2,4]. As 2 is common in both lists, it should be included only once.

Comment: There is two `2` in `[1,2,2,4]`, so it is included twice, not once. I've edited the question.

Comment: The dict comp is unnecessary as `Counter` implements union and intersection operations: `list((na | nb).elements())`. Additionally in your last example the output of `merge` should be `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: Perfect. Wonderful explanation